# input value not being passed through to ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass the name value through AJAX and `alert` the value out, whilst storing the value in a database. For some reason the value is not being picked up in AJAX and I'm not sure why because I have given my input field an `id` of `name` and referenced it in submit.js

```
<form method="post" id="submit_form">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="username"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="save_button" value="Submit">
</form> 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="" src="submit.js"></script>
```

```js
// in submit.js...

$('#save_button').click(function(e) {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        data: name,
        type: "post",
        url: "submit.php",
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Data Save: " + data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Fill it with `text/javascript` or remove it.

Comment: Your problem is here `var name = $('#name').val();` and `data: name,`

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a key/value pair to the `data` property of `$.ajax`.

To do this you can use an object:

```
data: { "name": name },
```

Alternatively you could `serialize()` the values contained within the `form`. This will make jQuery create an appropriately encoded querystring from the values of all the fields within the form specified.

```
data: $('#submit_form').serialize(),
```

Finally you could build a querystring yourself - although this is not considered best practice as jQuery will encode the values for you when using either of the above methods.

```
data: "name=" + name,
```

Answer (score 0):

change `data: name`
to   `data:{'name':name}`

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

simply this works to pass all form fields values to ajax

```
$('#save_button').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    data: jQuery('#submit_form').serialize(),
    type: "post",
    url: "submit.php",
    success: function(data){
      alert("Data Save: " + data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: the value is still not being picked up via ajax

Comment: what is your submit.php file? I should print this <?php print_r($_POST) ?>.
In order to receive any data into ajax response, something needs to be print in submit.php file.